# Error: invoke: the corresponding reloaded function was not found

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
class inject {
public:
    __forceinline bool injectDll()
    {

        HWND hWnd = LI_FN(FindWindowA).forwarded_safe_cached()(skCrypt("Window Class").decrypt(), skCrypt("Window Name").decrypt());
       

        DWORD pid;
        DWORD tid = LI_FN(GetWindowThreadProcessId).forwarded_safe_cached()(hWnd, &pid);
        if (!tid)
        {
            return false;
        }

        HANDLE hThread = LI_FN(OpenThread).forwarded_safe_cached()(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, tid);
        if (!hThread || hThread == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            return false;
        }

        HMODULE hMod = LI_FN(LoadLibraryExA).forwarded_safe_cached()("C:\\Windows\\System32\\od.dll", NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);
        if (!hMod)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!LI_FN(SetWindowsHookExW).forwarded_safe_cached()(3, (HOOKPROC)LI_FN(GetProcAddress).forwarded_safe_cached(), hMod, tid))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (PostThreadMessageW(tid, 0, 0, 0))
        {
            ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
            WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(hThread);


        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

creating a stream:

`std::thread thread_m(&inject::injectDll);`

I tried to solve it in different ways, passed the left arguments, filling in the function parameters. I tried to write a function in the classroom, and not in the classroom, but the same mistake, please tell me.

Comment: The call to `inject::injectDll()` requires an `inject` instance object. Where is it defined? Or make the member function `static`.